# Why does the .NET regex search engine find only one single match?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

The regex `(?=(\d+))\w+\1` applied to the "`456x56`" finds only one single match "56x56".

Why the search engine doesn't proceed any further to find the next match "`6x56`"?

Comment: Because the characters 56x56 are already consumed by `\w+\1`. You can't match them a second time.

Comment: That's not the "next match". They overlap. It starts looking for the next match *after the end* of the first match. If it worked the way you want, it would be useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The characters 56x56 are already consumed by `\w+\1`. You can't match them a second time.

If you want to search your string one position at a time, you need to put all the pattern in the lookahead, something like:

```
(?=((\d+)\w*\2))
```

The expected result is in the capture group 1. [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3D%28%28%5Cd%2B%29%5Cw*%5C2%29%29&i=456x56)

Since the lookahead is a zero-width assertion (only a test in other words) it doesn't consume characters, this way the regex engine will try each position in the string.